# Explain why $\big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2/2}dz \big)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(z^2 + u^2)/2}dzdu$

Tags: integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, normal-distribution

I came across the following when studying a proof related to the normal distribution:

$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2/2}\ dz \right)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(z^2 + u^2)/2}\ dz\ du$$

Is this some kind of identity? It was used as a step in the proof but I would like to know how it was arrived at?

Comment: Tonelli theorem.

Comment: Write out the square, rename one of the integration variables and then use indepence if I recall it correctly.

Comment: True if $Z$ and $U$ are statistically independent.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: No random variables in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}dxdy
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dxdy\\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}\underbrace{\left[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\right]}_{constant \ w.r.t.y}dy\\
&=\left[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\right]\left[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy\right]\\
&=\left[\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx\right]^2
\end{align}